# Gurobi cannot set or print (manually) value of variables

Tags: java, optimization, gurobi

I'm writing a program in Java with Gurobi 6.0.2 and I've some trouble about the management of variables, in particular I can't set or print them.

Example:

```
GRBEnv env = new GRBEnv();
GRBModel model = new GRBModel(env);
GRBVar x = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 0.0, GRB.SEMIINT, "x");
x.set(GRB.DoubleAttr.X, 10.0);
System.out.println(x.get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X));
```

NetBeans shows this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" gurobi.GRBException: Error at GRBVar.set
    at gurobi.GRBVar.set(GRBVar.java:141)
    at core.Optimize.main(Optimize.java:29)
Java Result: 1
```

This problem happens also when I resolved the relaxation model, so I can't retrive the value of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set start values for variables, you cannot use

```
x.set(GRB.DoubleAttr.X, 10.0);
```

but have to write

```
x.set(GRB.DoubleAttr.Start, 10.0);
```

Getting variable values only makes sense after you have solved the model.

Comment: I wrote this fragment of code only to verify if only works correctly because, after resolving the relaxation model, Gurobi shows a GRBException at GRBVar.get

Comment: That exception usually means that no primal solution was found (either because the model is infeasible or because the TimeLimit was reached).